# how to prevent combine ends of arcs of tikz-dependency

Tags: dependencies, tikz-pgf

How to prevent the arcs from combining with `tikz-dependency`, like

[image]

two arcs starting from "had" are separated from each other.

but in the picture generated by the following code, below they are not separated,

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}

\begin{dependency}[theme = simple, edge horizontal padding=3pt]
\begin{deptext}[column sep=1em]
A \& hearing \& is \& scheduled \& on \& the \& issue \& today \& . \\
\end{deptext}
\depedge{1}{3}{ATT}
\depedge{2}{3}{ATT}
\depedge{3}{8}{SBJ}
\depedge{3}{9}{PU}
\depedge{5}{8}{VC}
\depedge{4}{8}{TMP}
\depedge{6}{8}{PC}
\depedge{7}{8}{PC}
\end{dependency}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have read the `tikz-dependency` manual, and add the parameter 'edge horizontal padding', but the resulting picture is the same.

Is there a way to prevent the default arc combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you may want to use the `edge start offset x` and `edge end offset x` options. They are available since tikz-dependency v1.1 and documented on page 16 of the manual. If you apply them at the `depedge` level, they can shift horizontally the start/end point of each edge individually.

The example from the manual is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-dependency}

\begin{document}
\begin{dependency}[theme = simple]
 \begin{deptext}[column sep=1em]
  A \& hearing \& is \& scheduled \& on \& the \& issue \& today \& . \\
 \end{deptext}
 \deproot{3}{ROOT}
 \depedge{2}{1}{ATT}
 \depedge[edge start x offset=-6pt]{2}{5}{ATT}
 \depedge{3}{2}{SBJ}
 \depedge{3}{9}{PU}
 \depedge{3}{4}{VC}
 \depedge{4}{8}{TMP}
 \depedge{5}{7}{PC}
 \depedge[arc angle=50]{7}{6}{ATT}
\end{dependency}
\end{document}
```

[image: Image produced by above code]

Comment: Hi Andrew, I was aware of page 16 on the manual, but in this way, I need to manually adjust  all 'wrong' edge. Is there a global switch to separate edges(edges starting or ending at same node not merged)?

Comment: @icycandy In short: no, there isn't. On the other hand, you can easily use `\foreach` and increase the offsets of the edges programmatically.